# X Pages compatibility with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, xpages

I have an application developed in X-Pages which is working fine with all browsers and all versions of Internet Explorer except for 8. As soon as the user tries to access the application Internet Explorer 8 throws an error saying "Internet Explore has encountered a problem and needs to close." I tried to use the below code by Julian Buss in the beforeRenderResponse event of the xPage to  and the error disappeared but I still keep getting the error on each partial or full refresh. Is there any solution to this problem?

```
// X-UA-Compatible: IE=7
// X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(8, 8)) {
 var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
 var response = exCon.getResponse();
 response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");
}
```

Comment: Is there anything specific they're doing that causes it to break? I've had an app that broke for a user when using the ExtLib Value Picker on IE8, but I couldn't reproduce the crash on my installations of IE8 on XP or Windows 7. Also, is it IE8 standard or IE8 in compatibility mode? There's no way to prevent compatibility mode if it's enabled, you can only change the document mode (I blogged about that recently). I'm afraid I found IE8 horrendously poor at being able to identify the cause for those kinds of crashes.

Comment: This is not a XPages specific issue. Please check this out: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-has-encountered-a-problem-and-needs-to-close/

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft IE LifeCycle](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Internet+Explorer&Filter=FilterNO) support site phrases it a little cryptic, but basically says: "Out of support". So your best option is to follow their recommendation and upgrade to the latest IE version (if you have to stick to IE).

Alternatively if your client panics about keeping software current, you could introduce the [Chrome Frame Plugin](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) which nicely fits, since it is end of support too. It would lay dormant inside IE until you provide the header (which you would do in your XPage) that wakes it up.

Other than that: you have to dumb your app down for your IE users. You also could add the following code to a control:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <div style='border: 1px solid #F7941D; background: #FEEFDA; text-align: center; clear: both; height: 75px; position: relative;'>
        <div style='position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px; font-family: courier new; font-weight: bold;'><a href='#' onclick='javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none"; return false;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-cornerx.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Close this notice'/></a></div>
        <div style='width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; color: black;'>
          <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-warning.jpg' alt='Warning!'/></div>
          <div style='width: 275px; float: left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
            <div style='font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 12px;'>You are using an outdated browser</div>
            <div style='font-size: 12px; margin-top: 6px; line-height: 12px;'>For a better experience using this site, please upgrade to a modern web browser.</div>
          </div>
          <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.firefox.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-firefox.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Firefox'/></a></div>
          <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.browserforthebetter.com/download.html' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-ie8.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Internet Explorer 11'/></a></div>
          <div style='width: 73px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/download/' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-safari.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Safari'/></a></div>
          <div style='float: left;'><a href='http://www.google.com/chrome' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-chrome.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Google Chrome'/></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
```

Hope that helps